# How to add Mapbox telemetry 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT as dependency?

Tags: android, mapbox, telemetry

I just forked fresh mapbox library and tried to add it to my project as a module. Main problem is that gradle gives error when it's synchronising, because I can't access telemetry 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT

```
Error:Could not find com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-telemetry:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
Required by:
    MyApp:app:unspecified > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:MapboxGLAndroidSDK:5.0.0-SNAPSHOT
<a href="searchInBuildFiles">Search in build.gradle files</a>
```

How can I add telemetry services to my project?

Or it's impossible and I should be patient and just check for latest public Mapbox release in git history (currently it's 4.2.2 on Android), checkout and use that version and wait for a new public release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found out that top level gradle file was missing snapshot sonatype repository.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
}
```